# How do I change my operating system from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I would like to change my OS from Windows 7 ultimate (32 bit) to Ubuntu can I change it ? and what is the procedure?

- Where can I download or get Ubuntu software (web site) and how do I decide which version suits my PC?
- Can all the software which work in windows still work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Take a look here [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/107450) to help you decide which version you want.  If Win 7 is running OK then I would recommend the standard Ubuntu.  If you want the latest features go with 13.04 if you want the longest support 12.04.  The link provided by Alvar explains how to install.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there if you go onto the Ubuntu website or use the link provided you can download the Ubuntu OS (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), you will then need to decide what version you would like. I would recommend 12.04 LTS as you will have more support but you can try 13.04 which has the latest features.

Once you have downloaded the iso file you will need to burn it to a disk. Or you can you can put all the installation files onto a USB drive and run it. To do that you will need the following software (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Please make sure that backup all your files from your original OS before you proceed to installing Ubuntu as you will loose all you files unless you decide to dual boot, which I would recommend if you are not 100% sure that you want Ubuntu as you main operating system.

All your software will probably not work on Ubuntu such as Microsoft Office, Internet Explorer etc, but ubuntu does have lots of alternatives and there is a program call wine which you can use if you want to try and use Windows software of Ubuntu.

Hope this is some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

That's good to move to Open Source 
To Use Ubuntu :
Note That

Linux does not run Microsoft Windows Application, it's not support any Windows Application, Linus Full of Open Source Application , Work Better than Windows Application, but in Linux there is application to get best performance to do your job,

In Ubuntu , there is Ubuntu Software Center, you can find your different Applicatio that good to make your PC Smarter ..

You can find your alternative application in Linux, you have Open Office, Google_Chrome
,VLC player , Skype , and More ...

you can run Linux beside Microsoft Windows , Work Correctly , by Dual_Boot ..

You Can Download Ubuntu From Ubuntu Website: 
[Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Recommended 64-bit , if your processor architecture support 64bit. if not choose 32bit.

you can burn it on DVD or USB-Stick..